# Can TASM code run on NASM and vice versa?

Tags: assembly, nasm, tasm

I'm taking a course on computer organisation and architecture and as part of the course we have to learn assembly language. They tell us to install NASM but that TASM and MASM are also perfectly acceptable, although they won't help if I get problems with the latter two.

I'm on windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit so NASM doesn't work. After trying for two days to find a solution to get it to run on my computer I finally gave up. Now I have TASM running with DOSBox.

So my question is:

Will the NASM code samples they give me run on TASM? also if I start taking TASM tutorials will I be learning the exact same assembly that they are teaching even if they compile it with NASM?

I don't want to get wrong answers on the exam just because I'm used to a different compiler.

Comment: You didn't find the right tag because you didn't find the right site. This site is about computer science, not about programming. Migrating.

Comment: Are you sure `nasm` won't work on your box?  I have it running fine here on Win7/64 bit.  I believe tasm and nasm have slightly different syntaxes. nasm has a tasm compatibility mode, but I'm not sure about the reverse.

Comment: Download the Windows version of NASM, it will work fine on your computer.

Comment: OK i got my hello world to compile. The only thing is I needed dosbox to run the .exe because my PC is 64 bit and I got an error. But the answer to the question in the header seems to be: NO

Comment: by .exe I meant .com (!)

Comment: It doesn't matter what assembler you use, old 16 bit DOS programs won't run on 64 bit OS's without an emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TASM and NASM are very different assemblers.

- TASM is quite type-sensitive; NASM not at all.
- NASM uses macros heavily; TASM macros are quite clunky.
- NASM supports local symbols (using `.`); (most) TASM symbols are global.

And as @Peter Cordes points out:

- TASM and NASM have different ways of specifying numbers (TASM can't use `0x` prefixes);
- TASM allows the horrendous `mov ax, address` which means what's AT `address`, not `address`-as-a-value. True, this was for compatibility with (the even worse) MASM from Microsoft.

To avoid the last, **ALWAYS** use either `mov ax,offset address` or `mov ax,[address]` to avoid any ambiguity.

While the actual opcodes and registers of the assemblers are the same, all of the extra definitions around it use completely different syntax.

I used TASM for a couple of decades. Now I'm forced to use NASM - and [I don't like it very much](http://wiki.osdev.org/User:Johnburger/NASMCritique)...

Comment: MASM/TASM's "type safety" only works for static data anyway, so I don't see it as a big deal at all.  I like NASM's philosophy that you can tell how a line will assemble just by looking at it, without having to look somewhere else in the file.  I think it's weird and confusing to have magic operand-size voodoo inferring the operand-size from something else.  (I also really don't like that `mov reg, symbol` is a load, even without `[]`.)

Comment: I've never used NASM's struct syntax at all.  I haven't written anything with complicated data structures in asm, but I thought the struct syntax only worked for static/global data (which is of limited use for code that's part of a normal Linux program, for example).  e.g. asm code for a video encoder like x265.  BTW, I actually prefer yasm over nasm to assemble NASM-syntax asm files, partly because it generates long-NOPs by default for `ALIGN` directives.

Comment: I hate that last too! But I made it a rule to always _always_ **always** use either `OFFSET` or `[]`. My problem is that I want the assembler to tell me when I've done something dumb: `mov eax,[X]` never bodes well if `X` is a byte... worse if it's `mov [X],eax`!

Comment: NASM's local symbol syntax is the best part of it. If you're curious, look near the bottom of http://wiki.osdev.org/JohnBurger:Demo/x86/Desc

Comment: Yeah, I can see there's some value in having the assembler check for consistency between constants in the `rodata` section and the reg you load them into.  Anyway, your answer should probably mention the `[]` difference between assemblers.  That's one of the major ways that the same line can assemble to a different instruction on NASM vs. MASM.  You only claim that the opcodes (mnemonics) and registers are the same, but you should probably mention that memory/immediate operands are different!  Also that TASM will choke on `0xDEADBEEF` constants, instead requiring the less-readable `0DEADBEEFh`

Comment: @PeterCordes : Type safety can work for data on the stack too. You can declare function arguments when using the PROC directive giving each parameter a type. You can define local stack variables with the `local` directive if the `local` directive appears inside a PROC function. The local directive will take a type as one of the parameters.

Comment: @JohnBurger , then which of the three do you like? And if not among them, anything else?

Comment: @BumbleBee I don't chop and change tools regularly; once I learn of one tool's foibles, I either work around them or put up with them. So I use NASM since it's still maintained. TASM died long ago (Pentium Pro days?), and NASM is better (in some respects) than MASM. The other alternative of course is the Gnu Compiler Collection version (gas?) - but that uses a completely different syntax for x86, which I have never learned. It also uses source(s)-first-destination-last while MASM/TASM/NASM use Intel's destination-first-source(s)-last. It's all what you are used to.

Comment: @JohnBurger , can MASM's code be assembled with NASM then?

Comment: @BumbleBee They're very close. The two dialects have a lot in common, so some MASM code might need to be tweaked (for example, NASM doesn't use the reserved words "OFFSET" or "DUP"), and some expressions might need to be changed. But the differences are tiny compared to a gas/NASM translation!